# Setting precision/field width in operator<< for an entire vector

Tags: c++, c++17, iostream, cout, iomanip

The code below prints a vector to `std::cout`.

```
struct vect {
    double x;
    double y;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vect v){
    os << "[" << v.x << " " << v.y << "]";
    return os;
}

int main(){
    vect v = {1.0, 2.0};
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What would be a good way to control the width/precision of each field? I could hardcode it in `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vect v){
    os << "[" << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(7) << v.x << " " << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(7) << v.y << "]";
    return os;
}
```

but I would rather want to control it from the outside:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(7) << v << std::endl;
```

However I think this would only set the precision and width for the first field of the vector.

What I have in mind is to first "getw" and "getprecision" at the start of `operator<<` and then persist them to the other fields. Are there ways to retrieve these things from the stream, and is this basic design based on correct assumptions? (I'm not very confident about how iomanipulators work; I just know to send in `std::setw` before the data.)

Comment: @Ron Thanks; I know that. But the modification reverts after the next field is printed, doesn't it?

Comment: It is confusing that you have named your type the same as a standard library type which is very different.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Agree. It was a dummy name and I never use `using namespace`. Will change.

Comment: When I test it, the precision seems to persist on the stream.

Comment: @Ron Oh ok. But since `std::setw` isn't sticky, I guess the question is more or less unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as covered in comments, setprecision persists, but setw does not.

Supposing you want setw to apply to each individual field in your composition type, but not to the formatting characters around it. To do this, look at the width property, then set it for each of the numeric fields.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct coordinate {
    double x;
    double y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, coordinate p) {
    auto w = os.width();
    os << std::setw(0) << "["  // we don't want the width yet
       << std::setw(w) << p.x  // set width on specific field
       << " " 
       << std::setw(w) << p.y  // set width on specific field
       << "]";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    coordinate value = { 1.000019, 2.000019 };
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(7) << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::setw(7) << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(3) << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> [      1       2]  
> [1.00002 2.00002]  
> [  1   2]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done. Is it a sound design?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vect v){
    auto p = os.precision();
    auto w = os.width();
    os << "[" << std::setprecision(p) << std::setw(w) << v.x << " " << std::setprecision(p) << std::setw(w) << v.y << "]";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: This is already in your question? If not, edit it into the question, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Ah yes, this is basically what I did, with a few minor differences. Do you want the width applies to the left bracket but not the right bracket? You don't need precision.

Answer (score 0):

> However I think this would only set the precision and width for the first field of the vector.

I think you should verify this before spending more time trying to "solve" it.

(not really an answer, but I can't quote, etc in a comment)

Comment: So I was wrong about `std::setprecision` but not about `std::setw`. The general problem remains I think.

Comment: But now you don't "think", you *know*. Much better.

Comment: I was wrong. My question should actually have been about printing aligned matrices. That is the only reason for wanting to control the width.